# Rational Direction

Tags: geometry, dynamical-systems

What is mean by rational direction. This technical term is used to Define the definition of transitivity in multidimensional symbolic dynamics.

Comment: Probably that the coordinates of the direction vector are rational numbers.

Answer (score 1):

To me, rational direction would mean a vector whose coordinates (with respect to some canonical basis) are rational numbers. Or, since scalar multiples of a vector describe the same direction, any direction for which such a rational vector can be found. And since you can always multiply by the common denominator, this in turn means a direction which can be described by a vector with integer-only coordinates.

I don't know anything about the application of this term you're describing. If you need more detail on that, like a more specialized answer, then you should include a reference to that definition.